# How to connect to a Cassandra cluster with authentication in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.7. I am using `AuthProvider` to for authentication. I have tried two methods:

```
AuthProvider authProvider = new PlainTextAuthProvider("abcd", "xyz");
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withAuthProvider(authProvider).build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
```

and

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node)..withCredentials("abcd", "xyz").build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /127.0.0.1:9042: Host /127.0.0.1:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider.java:40)
```

What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: What you are doing should work. Can you include the code you are using to actually create a connection from the cluster.

Comment: @mikea I have added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change value of authenticator and authorizer in cassandra.yaml:

> authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
>
> authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer